# Request additional data on individual routes - ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I have the following setup:

```
this.resource('books', function(){
    this.route('book', {path: '/:id'} )
})

App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
    title: attr('string'),
    year: attr('number'),

    pages: hasMany('page')
})

App.Page = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string')
})
```

books route JSON

```
"books": 
    [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "title": "the hunger games"
         },
         {
            "id": 67,
            "title": "lord of the rings"
         },
         {
            "id": 89,
            "title": "the hobbit"
         }
    ]
```

example of `books/23` json

```
"book": {
    "id": 23,
    "title": "the hunger games",
    "year": 2008,

    "pages": [4, 5, 6]
}

App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('books')
    }
})
App.BooksBookRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('list', params.id)
    }
})
```

I'm trying to have a general list on the books route, so that it simply displays title and year. On navigating to `books/:id`, I want to force the route to make a request for the remaining data - ie: year, pages, and eventually the pages model.

With the above format, upon navigating to a specific book route (eg: `/book/23`), the route simply uses the store defined in `BooksRoute` and doesn't make a new request for the individual book. This results in data missing the year and pages info.
Is there any way I can force another request? Would I have to customize the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call reload on the model.  See documentation here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload

So for you:

```
App.BooksBookRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('list', params.id).then(function (book) {
          return book.reload();
        }
    }
})
```